# How to i Change URL Format in PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

i want to change URL 
`http://localhost/Self-Content/img.php?v=YQHsXMglC9A&fmt=hqdefault.jpg`
to
`http://localhost/Self-Content/bUTdUaVmj8o/mqdefault.jpg`

I'm Try this `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /img\.php\?v=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /img\.php\&fmt=([^\s]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [NC,R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ img.php?v=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ img.php?v=&fmt=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

I'm Using Wamp But When I try this code i'm getting this error
`Internal Server Error`

`The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have it like this inside `Self-Content/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Self-Content/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /img\.php\?v=([^&\s]+)&fmt=([^&\s]+)\s [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [NC,R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ img.php?v=$1&fmt=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for ans when i add this code in `.htaccess ` but i'm facing `500 Internal Server Error` in wamp what i can do know

Comment: Nothing in this code will cause 500 and I've tested them on my Apache. You must enable `mod_rewrite` and do check your `error.log` for exact reason of 500 error.